# Can't connect windows phone 8.1 for development

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I develop an app for windows phone 8.1, and I do everything the same as always, but suddenly I can't deploy to my phone. 
I see my phone connected (phone companion, file explorer) I can manipulate with files, photos, but I cant deploy. When I try development tools (e.g. WP Developer Power Tools or Visual Studio I always get "Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected" 
I tried to restart my phone (several times), restart IpOverUsbSvc, I even tried different usb ports, nothing helped... 
Any Ideas?

Comment: Try to restart Visual Studio. Then try to restart your PC. Then try to restart your phone. =) In most cases it should help.

Comment: none of these helped, I even tried several times in different order :/

Comment: Can you try with other PC to determine where is problem: PC or Windows Phone?

Comment: Good idea, I will try that, thanks.

Comment: I could not try, my phone on other pc with visual studio, but i tried to connect another phone here, and it is the same problem, so it must be the system problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went through many forums (including microsoft too) and it seems that the only solution is clean re-install of windows 10 and visual studio.
[In this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/52756054-de22-436d-9dce-f818f083683f/wp81windows-phone-developer-registration-81-unable-to-connect-to-a-phone?forum=wpdevelop), there is quite nice sum up of what to check before you resort to reinstall.